# Twitter API How to know if a user is following another user?

Tags: ios, swift, twitter

I made a follow/following button so I need to know if the user A is already following the user B.

I know I can get all his/her friends with [GET friends/ids](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/follow-search-get-users/api-reference/get-friends-ids) but I'd like to know if there is a shorter way (without looping on the whole list, with cursors, etc.).

(Additional info: I'm using the iOS SDK)

Comment: Looks like interview question. Please describe what did you tried for your problem will help you to get answer quickly.

Comment: I have a user twitter id and I'd like to know if I already follow him/her or not. I can scroll through all my friends which I can get from GET friends/ids but it takes time (several request to have them all) and I'd like to avoid that.

Comment: I'd like to know if there is a shorter to do this, for example the same request but with a param like "user_id" to know for this user in particular.

Comment: The only way I can think of is by storing all my friends in my iOS app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Twitter API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/follow-search-get-users/api-reference) has a dedicated endpoint for this situation: [`friendships/show`](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/follow-search-get-users/api-reference/get-friendships-show)

The answer will give you all the information about the relationship between these two users, you just need to specify their *screenname* or *user_id*.